# Firebase Compare users password

Tags: firebase

Are there any ways to compare users password on the new firebase. I review their get started but i was not able to find anything. I know im able to log them in again but i wanted to avoid that.

```
@IBAction func changePasswordPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        let formArray = [
            "email":"pprevalon@gmail.com",
            "oldPassword":"ismith",
            "newPassword":"ismith"

        ]

        let ihelprController = ihelprAPI()

        if ihelprController.checkIfFormIsEmpty(formArray){





        }else{

            print("form is not fill up")
        }







    }
```

Comment: You should NEVER store user's passwords, if you have a security breach that data leak would be a nightmare. I suggest reading up on "hashing" before going further down this route.

Comment: I was trying to compare that the password but you completely right about the security issue